# Can one reduce the study of unbounded operators to the one of bounded operators?

Tags: functional-analysis, unbounded-operators, functional-calculus

So I am not very well-versed in functional analysis, but while studying a problem from theoretical solid-state physics I came across the following question:

Suppose $\mathcal{H}$ is a complex Hilbert-space and you have an unbounded densely defined self-adjoint operator  $H \colon D \subset \mathcal{H} \to \mathcal{H}$ which spectrally decomposes as
$$
\begin{align}
H = \int_{\lambda \in \sigma(H)} \lambda dP_\lambda, 
\end{align}
$$
where $P_\lambda$ is the projection operator on the eigenvalue $\lambda \in \sigma(H)$ in the spectrum of $H$. For simplicity, assume the spectrum is bounded below, but "includes" $+ \infty$. Now suppose that $P_\lambda \overset{S.O.T}{\to} \tilde{P}$ in the strong operator topology for $\lambda \to + \infty$.
Let now $f \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous (or maybe just Borel-measurable) strictly monotonically increasing function with $\lim_{x \to + \infty} f(x) = 1$. By functional calculus, one could build
$$
\begin{align} 
f(H) = \int_{\lambda \in \sigma(H)} f(\lambda) dP_\lambda.
\end{align}
$$
Through the S.O.T convergence, the spectrum of this operator should include $1$ and this operator should also be bounded and as such could be extended from $D$ to the whole of $\mathcal{H}$.

Either I am doing something terribly wrong (which could be the case), or it seems that I reduced the operator $H$ to a bounded operator $f(H)$. I am wondering what information gets lost, since I can throw the second operator on any vector of $\mathcal{H}$ and would get a new well-defined vector.

Is there some literature on this? Am I performing certain things which are not allowed?

I would be thankful for any further indication.

Comment: In von Neumann's book (Foundations of Quantum Mechanics) this is how the spectral decomposition of unbounded selfadjoint operators is constructed: you take the Cayley transform $(H+i)/(H-i)$, which is a unitary operator (after a discussion of deficiency index), which has a spectral decomposition.

Comment: That I get, but here I already start with a slef-adjoint operator, the notion of deficiency subspace is therefore not useful to me. This construction is weird to me since I have the "feeling" that the bounded operator captures all the information of the unbounded one.

Comment: I think you are perfectly right and your construction works (I was just mentioning a similar situation, when an unbounded operator is transformed to a unitary, and thus bounded, operator)